# Sanitization of User-Supplied Regular Expressions in PHP

Tags: php, regex, sanitization

I want to create a website where users can test regular expressions (there are many out there already...such as this one: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm). Basically, the user provides a regular expression and some sample text, and the results of the regex evaluation will be spit back.

I want to evaluate the regex on the server side with the PHP "preg_*" functions. Is there a way to sanitize the supplied regex? What are the security vulnerabilities that I should be concerned about?

Comment: Why don't you use JS for that? This way you don't have to sanitize anything as it will be executes on the client side.

Comment: I should have added that in addition to evaluating the regex on the user-supplied sample text, I also want to evaluate the regex on a "secret" string, that resides on the server. I don't know of a way to do that in JS without the user knowing what the string is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think PHP itself will check the regex.
Here's a sample script I made :

```
// check for input, and set max size of input
if(@!empty($_POST['regex'])
    && @!empty($_POST['text'])
    && strlen($_POST['regex'])<1000
    && strlen($_POST['text'])<2000
    ){
    // set script timeout in case something goes wrong (SAFE MODE must be OFF)
    $old_time=ini_get('max_execution_time');
    if(!set_time_limit(1)) die('SAFE MODE MUST BE OFF'); // 1 sec is more then enough

    // trim input, it's up to you to do more checks
    $regex=trim($_POST['regex']);
    // don't trim the text, it can be needed
    $input=$_POST['text'];
    // escape slashes
    $regex=preg_replace('/([\\/]+)?//', '\/', $regex);

    // go for the regex
    if(false===$matched=@preg_match('/'.$regex.'/', $input, $matches)){
            // regex was tested, show results
            echo 'Matches: '.$matched.'<br />';
            if($matched>0){
                    echo 'matches: <br />';
                    foreach($matches as $i =>  $match){
                            echo $i.' = '.$match.'<br />';
                }
            }
    }
    // set back original execution time
    set_time_limit($old_time);
}
```

Anyways, **NEVER EVER use eval() with user submitted strings**.

Additionally, you can do some simple minimalistic sanitizing, but that's up to you. ;)

Comment: instead of escaping the regex string on your own you could use [preg_quote](http://php.net/preg_quote)

Comment: Are you sure setting max_execution_time will actually limit the time preg is running? I was under the impression that DL calls would always complete, and max_execution_time would only klill the php script after the preg call returns. That would mean that users yould still easily bog down your system by providing evil expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow user-submitted values for `preg_replace` **make sure** you disallow the [`e` flag](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)! Not doing so could allow a malicious user to delete your entire site, or worse.

Otherwise, the worst thing that can happen is what the other answers already point out. Set a low script timeout, and maybe you should even make sure that the page can only be called X times per minute.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can think of is that someone can DOS you by entering a bad regex (one that is O(2^n) or O(n!) or whatever), and the easiest way to prevent this might be to set your page timeout short.

Comment: ...or limit the backtrace level of PREG.

Answer (score 0):

If the regex is being stored in a database, you should use whatever method you would normally use to escape the data, such as prepared statements.

Otherwise, my only concern is that the user could supply malicious regex in the sense that it could contain a mischeviously complex regex, and I'm not sure there is a way to check that.

One thought is that you could make your regex evaluator all client side by doing it in JS, but there are inconsistencies between php's preg functions and JavaScript regex functions.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik there are now "vulnerabilities" when trying to evaluate user-supplied regexps. The worst thing that could possibly happen is - like erik points out - a DOS attack or fatal error within your script.

I'm afraid to tell you that you won't be (even theoretically) able to "sanitize" every possible regexp out there. The best you can do is to check for lexical and/or syntactic errors.