# How can I check if a regular expression is not harmful in PHP

Tags: php, regex, forms, security

I am working on a project. This project have a user interface that we wrote in PHP. In the management part, there is a form input where the user needs to enter a regular expression. As I know, I can not check if is a regex or not, because every string is a regex.  What I want to do is check whether this input is proper or not? Which way I can do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "harmful"? Do you want to check whether or not the string is a *valid* regex, or whether or not it's a *malicious* regex?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371445/sanitization-of-user-supplied-regular-expressions-in-php

Comment: Well, I'd like to see a sample of a harmful regex.

Comment: @juhana: `^(a*a*)*$` is a classic. Try it on `aaaaaaaaaaaaaab` and watch your CPU burn.

Comment: @Tim, <0.02 sec (even with much longer string) in PHP/Perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very hard to do this by analysing the regex (short of actually parsing the regex itself.

I suggest you rather use conservative settings for [`pcre.backtrack-limit` and `pcre.recursion_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php#ini.pcre.backtrack-limit).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you expect the program to do.  If you are writing a regex tester, you simply need to have another field where they can input a string to check it against.  Then use `String.test(/regex/)` or `String.match(/regex/)` to see if it is good for that string.

Comment: It is not a regex tester, I am taking a regex from user and send it to a program that is written with python.